# What is the best library to manage a wiimote?

Tags: c++, c, wiimote

There are many libraries that manage the wiimote but I am looking for the "best" one, or at least that has the following features:

- open-source
- portable (at least **Win32 and Linux**)
- written and usable in **c or c++**
- good coverage of wiimote devices

I rely on people that already used such library. Google is good source of information but it doesn't know which one is best library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you will use multiple wiimotes, don't use wiiuse library. i am working on a stereo system with two wiimotes using wiiuse library but wiiuse made  me crazy( it gives delayed ir tracking data ) and i decided to change my library wiiuse from wiiyourself

Answer (score 4):

Some friends of mine have had good luck with [wiiuse](https://github.com/MJL85/wiiuse/). It's in C, for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: I've used this a little bit.  It works well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this:

http://www.codeplex.com/WiimoteLib

http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/14/1879033.aspx

It may not be exactly what you are asking for, but with Mono you'll have the cross platform part of it.

Comment: the second one is for C# and VB.NET :(

Comment: and the first one too :(

Comment: thanks for the downvote.  Why can't you use C++ to access it?

Comment: Tim, you've mentioned that you can use Mono to compile.  And you can reference from pretty much anything.  I think that downvote was unfair.

Answer (score 2):

What about [Johnny Chung Lee](http://johnnylee.net/projects/wii/) - it's .Net but it's open source and could converted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what your looking for:

http://wiiuse.sourceforge.net/

Open-sourced, multi-platform and written in C/C++. They are looking for a OSX developper though, so I'm guessing it doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://github.com/MJL85/wiiuse will do? Seems to have a lot of features and supports Windows and Linux, AND it is c.